# Clojure exception not caught

Tags: exception, clojure, try-catch, finally

I am learning Clojure, and I would like to create a macro that works like Javas try-catch.
If an exception is thrown, the exception should be returned. Otherwise, the result should be returned.
Any resource that is open should also be closed in the finally section (Without the use of with-open). However, I do have one problem except not being caught that I don't know how to solve. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
(defmacro my-try 
  ([expression] 
   `(try 
      ~expression
      (catch Exception e# e#)
      )
   )
  ([[value variable] expression] 
   `(let [~value ~variable] 
      (try
        ~expression
        (catch Exception e# e#)
        (finally (if (instance? java.io.Closeable ~value) (.close ~value)))
        )
      )
   )
  )
```

When I try to open and read from a file that does not exist:

```
(def v (my-try [s (FileReader. (File. "missing-file"))] (. s read)))
(println v)
```

I get the following error:

```
Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at java.io.FileInputStream/open0 (FileInputStream.java:-2).
missing-file (Det går inte att hitta filen)
```

I suspect that this error message is an uncaught exception because (1) it does not follow the structure of other exceptions, and (2) if I change the format of the exception return, such as adding a specific message, the error message still does not change.

Any help in finding out what is at fault is highly appreciated!
Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `(let [~value ~variable]`, `~variable` is evaluating to `(FileReader. (File. "missing-file"))`, but that's outside of the `try`. It would become something like this:

```
(let [s (FileReader. (File. "missing-file"))]
    (try
        (. s read)
        . . .
    ))
```

Move the `let` into the `try`, then `expression` into the `let` body.

---

Also, like in all languages, `(catch Exception e# e#)` is pretty much universally a bad idea. Throwing away errors becomes a nightmare once anything remotely non-trivial happens, since you've thrown out your only evidence of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess you mean something like this: (let [~value ~variable] (~expression)). If I do that, won't the ~value in the finally clause be un-instantiated?

Comment: Yes. You may need to do something messy like have a `volatile` in an outer `let` that you place `value` into in the `try`, then dereference it in the `finally` (`volatile`s are like `atom`s without the safety overhead).

Comment: Ok. I will look into that. However, I tried this and I seams like it works. What do you think of this solution: `([[value variable] expression] 
   '(try
      (let [~value ~variable] 
        (try
           ~expression
           (catch Exception e# (.toString e#))
           (finally (if (instance? java.io.Closeable ~value) (.close ~value)))))
      (catch Exception e# (.toString e#))
      )
    )`
You might have to copy and format some...

Comment: I would still get rid of the `except`. Having a `finally` is definitely helpful for ensuring that files are closed (this is essentially what Python's `with` does; kind of), but exception handling shouldn't be done unless you know for sure that you're able to correctly handle the error. By catching the error and printing it, you're preventing functions up the call stack from handling the error on your behalf (since they may be in a better place to recover than you are lower down), and you're also throwing away the stack-trace; an invaluable resource when debugging.